# persist an array after UUPS upgrade

Tags: solidity, arrays, contract-upgrading

I have a contract that I'm attempting to store the tax rates on. The issue I'm running into is `taxKeys` will randomly reset to empty after UUPS upgrade. This is completely random as sometimes it will reset and sometimes it will not.

I'm able to run `taxRateAdd()` to add a new recipient. The address is stored properly. After updating I can verify the address is stored in `isInTaxMap`. However, sometimes it will not persist `taxKeys` and will return empty array. This causes `taxRateCount()` and `taxRateRecipients()` to fail.

I can't understand why it's doing this. Some upgrades will persist `taxKeys` and others do not. What would cause `taxKeys` to reset like this?!

```
    mapping(address => bool) public isInTaxMap;
    mapping(address => string) private taxRecipientName;
    mapping(address => uint256) private taxRecipientRate;
    address[] private taxKeys; 

    function taxRateAdd(address recipientAddress, string memory recipientName, uint256 recipientTaxRate) onlyOwner public returns (bool){     
        taxRecipientName[recipientAddress] = recipientName;
        taxRecipientRate[recipientAddress] = recipientTaxRate;
        if(!isInTaxMap[recipientAddress]) {
            isInTaxMap[recipientAddress] = true;
            taxKeys.push(recipientAddress);
        }
        return true;
    }

    function taxRateDelete(address recipientAddress) onlyOwner public returns (bool){
        if(!isInTaxMap[recipientAddress]) {
            delete taxRecipientName[recipientAddress];
            delete taxRecipientRate[recipientAddress];
            delete isInTaxMap[recipientAddress];  
            return true;      
        }
        return false;
    }    

    function taxRateCount() public view returns (uint256){
        return taxKeys.length;
    }

    function taxRateRecipients() public view returns(address[] memory){
        return taxKeys;
    }

    function taxRateTotal() public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 recipientTaxRate = 0;
        for(uint i; i < taxKeys.length; ++i){
            recipientTaxRate = recipientTaxRate + taxRecipientRate[taxKeys[i]];
        }
        return recipientTaxRate;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think there's a bug in the code you've shown. It's probably in the way you're handling the upgrade

Comment: Probably unrelated but, while is `taxRateDelete` checking that the `recipientAddress` is not in the `isInTaxMap` (`if(!isInTaxMap[recipientAddress])`) to delete it? Does not make sense. It should check `if(isInTaxMap[recipientAddress])`.

Comment: So, this is the implementation contract? Can you also share the proxy contract?